# how to build a self-extracting JAR in Java

Tags: java, maven, jar, self-extracting

I am trying to build an installer for a Java application and would like to build a JAR which extracts itself.  The JAR will be built using Maven assembly and will have a main class specified in the manifest.  I want the main class to extract the rest of the JAR into a specified directory.  The JAR will contain other JARs and some docs.  I have found other questions, for example, ([How to copy file inside jar to outside the jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308221/how-to-copy-file-inside-jar-to-outside-the-jar)) but they don't address a self extracting JAR.  I would like to know how to 1) obtain the location and name of the JAR from which the main is being executed, 2) copy the contents of the JAR into a specified directory.

**UPDATE**: I would also appreciate answers which address how to build an installer for a Maven Java application (using Eclipse) in general.

Comment: What is the problem with keeping the JAR as it is and call ```java -jar MainClass" to execute your program?

Comment: I would like the user to be able to access the files inside the JAR such as docs, configuration files, etc...  I also would like to run some of the configuration files independently.

Comment: You can have access to your the files in a JAR so why do you need to extract them?

Answer (score 1):

If you have configurations that you want the user to update then don't include them in your jar file. You have a couple of options.

One is to write out default config files if they don't already exist.

The second one is to use [IzPack](http://izpack.org/) to provide a installer jar that will copy default configs that the user can then edit.

If you want an example of how IzPack works you can download [Squirrel](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/), which is an SQL tool, that uses IzPack to install itself.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I don't think that IzPack license allows for commercial use.

Comment: Yup I think you are right.  I must have been looking at the website license.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this answer works for me: [How to write a Java program which can extract a JAR file and store its data in specified directory (location)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529611/how-to-write-a-java-program-which-can-extract-a-jar-file-and-store-its-data-in-s) except I want to skip over copying the main class file as well as skip creating the folders on its path, so if the main class resides in a package that begins with say, "com", then just add

```
if(file.getName().startsWith("com"))
    continue;
```

below

```
java.io.File f = new java.io.File(destDir + java.io.File.separator + file.getName());
```

Comment: I still don't understand the interest of it. Being able to modify config file when they are extracted?

Comment: Yes, the user must have access to config files, docs, etc. which are packaged in the jar.

Comment: What happen when you need to update the jar? The files are replaced?

Comment: Good point.  I could not overwrite the config files if they already exist.