# Write to external file (local file system) from JAR

Tags: java, file, jar, external, executable

After exhausting the internet looking for the proper way to write a stream of data within a running JAR file, I have no idea how to take a stream of data, (say a string) and output to a `*.txt` file next to the `*.jar`.  Here's my writing attempt:

```
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream("some string".getBytes("UTF-8"));
OutputStream resStreamOut = new FileOutputStream(new File("/dir-next-to-jar/some.txt"));
int readBytes;
byte[] buffer = "some string".getBytes();
while ((readBytes = stream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    resStreamOut.write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775303/read-properties-file-outside-jar-file/41794050#41794050) is how I've already successfully loaded a local file next to the JAR into the JAR:

```
InputStream stream = ThisClassName.class.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/dir-next-to-jar/some.txt");
```

So, how do I write new data to the same file I loaded into a stream to the JAR?

It seems like the obvious solution would be to reverse the action I took loading the `*.text` file into the JAR, but this is proving to be impossible.

**Note: I use a `String` as the data type of interest here, but in reality, I'm interested in writing a `JSONObject` and `BufferedImage` out from the JAR to a file.**

Please help!!!

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the code that you posted in the first snippet?

Comment: i'm not exactly sure.  i came up with it by taking bits of this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308221/how-to-copy-file-inside-jar-to-outside-the-jar

Comment: Well is it not working? Does it throw an exception? I'm asking *what* the problem is, not *why* :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have the data as a String, how about using Apache's FileUtils:

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#writeStringToFile(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)
You can write txt into a file with one line.

Comment: Use of third party libraries incurs a significant penalty: They reduce the portability of the program and are more susceptible to bugs than Java SE.  Using a third party library for something that can be done with three lines of code does not seem like a beneficial trade-off to me.

Comment: by the looks of if, an ApacheV2 library should work fine under a GPLv3 project - https://www.apache.org/licenses/GPL-compatibility.html