# Where should I place my sqlite database in my java maven project

Tags: java, sqlite, maven, javafx

Since putting in resources folder made the database in to read-only. I wanted my database to be in the jar file.

Comment: Why do you want the database in “the jar file”?  Deploying a JavaFX application including JavaFX components in a single jar file isn’t recommended see [packaging info in the JavaFX tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info).

Comment: You have some misunderstandings here. The contents of the resources directory will become part of the jar file. And anything placed in the jar file is necessarily read-only.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in comments by James_D:

> The contents of the resources directory will become part of the jar file. And anything placed in the jar file is necessarily read-only.

How to rectify this depends on what you want to do.

1. You can install it on another machine and access over the network.
2. You could create a new database on the local machine.

   - see [`System.getProperties()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()) documentation for finding local file locations.
3. If you want to seed data from an existing database in resources, then [copy it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308221/how-to-copy-file-inside-jar-to-outside-the-jar).
4. If read-only mode is sufficient, you may be able to access the db in read only mode when it is stored in a jar, though I wouldn’t guarantee that it would work as expected.

Beyond these generalities I don’t think there is specific info to be provided without more specifics on your app.

For a tutorial on connecting JavaFX and SQLite:

- [eden coding JavaFX db tutorial](https://edencoding.com/connect-javafx-with-sqlite/).