# Access AWS credentials file in WAR

Tags: java, spring, maven, amazon-web-services

I am making a Java application that uses, Spring, Maven and the AWS-SDK-Java. In order to the AWS SDK to work I have to place the `AWSCredentials.properties` file inside the "MyProject/src/main/resources" folder.

So far so so good. Then I have to create a `.war` file. To do that I use `mvn install` command and voilá.

Now inside the `.war` created, the file I want to access is in the "/WEB-INF/classes/" folder and I need to read it.

How can I access this file inside the war so I can read its content? I have experimented with `ServeltContext` but so far nothing I try works!

Comment: A quick way to see what's in a war file (on a *nix OS) is to use tar + grep. E.g, this command will show you all the properties files in your war: tar tvf <war file> | grep properties

Comment: A `.war` is a webapp archive. Compiled sources usually go to `/WEB-INF/classes`, so you should search the file in `/WEB-INF/classes/main/resources`

Comment: Alrigth, now I know where the file is! How to I tell me webapp to read it? I will update this question now !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do it. I can access the file by using:

`InputStream inputStream = 
      getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/resources/email/file.txt");`

As explained in this discusison:
[Reading a text file in war archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242782/reading-a-text-file-in-war-archive)

Answer (score 2):

It is generally not a good practice to keep credential in code package (war). Instead I would suggest you use [IAM Roles](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html).

This will make it easy for you to move your code from one AWS account to another (say dev environment to production). Since the code will be submitted to a version control system which will be accessed by many, it is also good from a security point of view to use IAM roles.