# Where can I store JSON file in the Jersey 2.18 folder structure

Tags: java, jersey

I want to get some data on the server side from a `JSON` file but I dont know where can I put the file in Jersey 2.18 folder structure?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Very vague question. Store wherever you like as long as you can access it-  check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664579/recommended-way-to-save-uploaded-files-in-a-servlet-application/18664715#18664715

Comment: Put it in the classpath, then see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1464291/2587435)

Comment: can not I put it in the resourses folder? src-main-resources

Comment: Yup, that's ends up being the classpath (if you're using maven)

Comment: Note that it is Jersey, not GlassFish that is 2.18, so I edited your question. Secondly, the file location is not a factor for Jersey, it is for your WAR file structure. Here is a [question regarding reading a text file from a WAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242782/reading-a-text-file-in-war-archive) that may help you out.