# Fetch .xlsx from .war file java

Tags: java

How do I fetch a `.xlsx` file from a Java `/src/resources folder` (from `.war` file) in Java? I need it in a File class format.

Comment: Are you using maven or how are you creating your project?

Comment: Yeah I'm using maven

Comment: Did you try anything? If yes, please add code. Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242782/reading-a-text-file-in-war-archive