# Class object & Classloader object difference ? and also one api difference?

Tags: java

I am trying to read the resource by the class loader.

but meanwhile, I found that , the class object also could finish such a thing.

my code is like this.

1. Teacher.class.getResource("1.txt");
2. Teacher.class.getClassLoader.getResource("1.txt");

the two ways could get the resource I wanted, however, I don't understand the underlying theory.

Is there anybody who can help me ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6608848/931982

Comment: after I tracked the source code, found code snippet like this.

    name = resolveName(name);
            ClassLoader cl = getClassLoader0();
            if (cl==null) {
                // A system class.
                return ClassLoader.getSystemResource(name);
            }
            return cl.getResource(name);

so the answer is method 1 will call method 2. 

Thanks all the same.

Answer (score 3):

Just checked the specification and it says this:

> Class.getResource(String resource)
>
> ClassLoader.getResource(String resource)

**Class's getResource() - documentation states the difference:**

> This method delegates the call to its class loader, after making these
>   changes to the resource name: if the resource name starts with "/", it
>   is unchanged; otherwise, the package name is prepended to the resource
>   name after converting "." to "/". If this object was loaded by the
>   bootstrap loader, the call is delegated to
>   ClassLoader.getSystemResource.