# Trying to load image using ImageIO.read(class.getResource(URL)) but getResource is returning null

Tags: java, bufferedimage, javax.imageio, getresource

I've been making a 2D game with my buddy and I've been learning a lot about some basic game dev concepts through some Youtube tutorials. One of the things I was learning about is sprites (for those that don't know, 2D images to render to the screen) and how to use them in my game. I've been using `ImageIO.read(this.class.getResource(pathToMySprite))` but it seems that `getResource()` is returning `null` for some reason.

I've been screwing around with the path a little, adding "/" in front of it, removing "/", putting the user.dir property to see if it needed the whole path, and I'm still getting the same error.

```
TILE_TEXTURES(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/textures/tile.png");
//ENTITY_TEXTURES("/textures/entity.png");
private BufferedImage img;

private SpriteSheet(String path) {

System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
try {
   //TODO: Fix this error, don't know what's wrong.
     img = ImageIO.read(SpriteSheet.class.getResource(path)); // error here!!!
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }

public BufferedImage getImage() {
        return img;
}
```

Any and all help is appreciated.
I haven't been commenting the code (I usually do that when I get to place where I can sit back and be happy with what I've finished) but it's a pretty small class so I think you guys will be able to understand what's going on just fine.

The folder that holds the image **IS** in the class path of my project.
I've also included the error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.brickbattle.client.src.gui.Sprite.<clinit>(Sprite.java:7)
    at com.brickbattle.client.src.objs.Tile.<init>(Tile.java:67)
    at com.brickbattle.client.src.objs.Player.initPlayerNum(Player.java:19)
    at com.brickbattle.client.src.util.BrickBattle.init(BrickBattle.java:114)
    at com.brickbattle.client.src.util.BrickBattle.run(BrickBattle.java:85)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null! //HERE IS ERROR
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.brickbattle.client.src.gui.SpriteSheet.<init>(SpriteSheet.java:17)
at com.brickbattle.client.src.gui.SpriteSheet.<clinit>(SpriteSheet.java:8)
```

**Thanks again!**

Comment: This post might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608795/what-is-the-difference-between-class-getresource-and-classloader-getresource

Comment: Instead of using `this.class.getResource()` try `getClass().getResource()`

Answer (score 5):

This problem is basically unrelated to ImageIO, but rather how `Class`/`ClassLoader.getResource` or `getResourceAsStream` works.

For an explanation, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6608848/1428606).

In any case, these ways of obtaining a resource **will only be able to read from classpath** (ie. `user.dir` will never help here).

This should work:

```
ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/path/to/resource"));
```

Where the path is relative to the *root* of the classpath (specified by the leading /).

If your resources are not on the classpath, simply use:

```
ImageIO.read(new File("path/to/resource");
```

Where the path is relative to the directory your application *was launched from*.