# How to pass a file location as a parameter as a string?

Tags: java, swing, loadimage

Currently I pass a hardcoded string file location to my object method which uses the string in the `.getResources()` method to load an image file.  I am now trying to chooses an image using a load button and pass the loaded file location as a string into the `getResource()` method.  I am using the `filename.getAbsolutePath()` method to retrieve the file location then passing the `filename` variable into the object method however this provides me with the following error - 
Exception in thread `"AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException.` 
The line of code that it points to having the error is the `.getResources` line where the image is loaded.  I will post the code below to better understand my problem.

```
btnLoad.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
              @Override
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                 JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
                 if (fc.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
                 {
                    File loadImage = fc.getSelectedFile();
                    String filename = loadImage.getAbsolutePath();
                    filename = filename.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\");
                    picLocation = filename;
                    ImageSwing imageSwing = new ImageSwing(filename);
                    System.out.println(filename);
                 }
              }
```

The output of the file name is correct yet it still wont pass into the object.

```
  public class ImageSwing extends JFrame
  {
  public JLabel label;

  public ImageSwing(String S){

  super("Card Stunt");                //Window Title
  setLayout(new FlowLayout());        //lookup grid layout


  Icon flag = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(S));          
  label = new JLabel(flag);
  label.setToolTipText(S);
  setSize(1350, 800);
  //setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1200, 760));

  }//main
 }
```

Comment: is the file under your class environment? because you are calling getClass().getResource(S) this will retrieve file begining with classpath + filename

Comment: Can you put the full exception (including stack trace)? Have you tried stepping through with a debugger and looking to see just what is null?

Comment: Another tip for using string filenames is to always us forward slashes to separate directories in the path. Java will sort it out.

Comment: what is the output of the line `System.out.println(filename);`?

Comment: Without knowing your directory structure it's hard to help. See [the tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html#getresource) and also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22733881/java-swing-unable-to-load-image-using-getresource), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343187/loading-resources-using-getclass-getresource) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17002906/trying-to-load-image-using-imageio-readclass-getresourceurl-but-getresource).

Comment: Having an absolute filename, why not just invoke the constructor of ImageIcon that takes a String as parameter (instead of URL)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you create an absolute filename with `loadImage.getAbsolutePath()`, but then you try to use this as a [class path resource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) with `new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(S))`.

Instead, you should just pass the absolute filename, as a string, to `ImageIcon`:

```
Icon flag = new ImageIcon(S);
```

Also, don't forget to add the label to the frame...

```
getContentPane().add(label);
```

Also, I'm not on Windows right now, but I don't think `filename.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\");` is necessary.

Comment: Icon flag = new ImageIcon(S);, please why Icon from ImageIcon, then you have to test for instanceof, becase if I'm remember correctly not all ImageIcons can to be Icon, rest is correct, plus one

Comment: @mKorbel Not sure what you mean, I just copied that part from your code. But since [`ImageIcon` implements `Icon`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html) no casting is needed.

Comment: What *I think* @mKorbel wants is to use `ImageIcon flag = new ImageIcon(S)` instead. Then you don't have to use `if (flag instanceof ImageIcon)` to test if the `Icon` is an `ImageIcon`.