# I am not able load image using getClassLoader Method

Tags: java, image, class, inputstream

Below is the code that I am trying to use.

```
 InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(Tester.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("appResources/img/GESS.png"));
 Image image=null;  
 try {
         image = ImageIO.read(in);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 System.out.println(image);
```

'image' comes null when I am printing it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getResourceAsStream returns null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570523/getresourceasstream-returns-null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
InputStream in = Tester.class.getResourceAsStream("your/path");
Image image=null;  
try {
    image = ImageIO.read(in);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(image);
```

The value or `your/path` is either `appResources/img/GESS.png` or `/appResources/img/GESS.png` depending on your maven configuration and the directory you setup for your project.

For instance, if you add the following entry to your `pom.xml` file:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/appResources</directory>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Then, you can get the same resource by using a shorter path since your program *knows* where to look for resources:

```
InputStream in = Tester.class.getResourceAsStream("img/GESS.png");
Image image=null;  
try {
    image = ImageIO.read(in);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(image);
```

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16571046/4862968) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17003272/4862968).

Comment: it prints 'null'.

Comment: Hmm did you check your resource file path? Is it a maven project?

Comment: yes, it is a maven project. absolute path to image  /XXXX/src/main/webapp/appResources/img/Flag_of_the_United_Kingdom.svg.png

Comment: Did you set your resource directory in your pom.xml?
 `<build>
        <!-- Set resource directory -->
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp/appResources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
</build>`

Comment: which pom.xml? there are two different war files XXXX and YYYY. I have get this file from XXXX war to YYYY . So do I need to add this directory to YYYY war?

Comment: You should have a structure like this : https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-web-application-project-with-maven/

Comment: Yeah, it is the same.

Answer (score 0):

you can use InputStream instream=Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("appResources/img/GESS.png");

Answer (score 0):

you use like this
InputStream instream=Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("appResources/img/GESS.png");

Answer (score 0):

Here are two utility methods I'm using for image loading.

```
public static Image getImage(final String pathAndFileName) {
    try {
        return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getURL(pathAndFileName));
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        //logger.error(e);
        return null;
    }
}

public static URL getURL(final String pathAndFileName) {
    return Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(pathAndFileName);
}
```