# why ClassLoader.getResource("/pkg/readme.txt") always return null with resource name with a leading slash?

Tags: java

I googled a lot but still don't understand 
Why ClassLoader.getResource("/pkg/readme.txt") always return null?
otherwise without the leading slash, ClassLoader.getResource("pkg/readme.txt") can return a correct URL.

I do understand the diff between those methods in Class and ClassLoader.

NOTE: I'm not asking the diff between Class.getResource() and ClassLoader.getResource() because I get it. My concern is on ClassLoader.getResource() does not work for a resource name which starts with a leading slash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My concern is on `ClassLoader.getResource()` does not work for a resource name which starts with a leading slash

That's because there are no resource names that start with a leading slash.  By definition a resource name is "a '/'-separated path name that identifies the resource" - the components are *separated by* slashes, not *preceded by* them.

`someClass.getResource("/pkg/readme.txt")` is equivalent to `someClass.getClassLoader().getResource("pkg/readme.txt")`, the leading slash is *not* part of the resource name but rather an indication to `Class.getResource` that it should *not* prepend the class's package to the path it passes to the classloader.  Without the leading slash:

```
someClass.getResource("pkg/readme.txt")
```

would be equivalent to

```
someClass.getClassLoader().getResource("com/example/pkg/readme.txt")
```

(assuming `someClass` is in the package `com.example`)

Comment: As I said I do understand the diff between Class and ClassLoader.And I do understand what you said.  But my question is why ClassLoader.getResource("/pkg/readme.txt") does not work with a leading slash.

Comment: @FengXi because that's what the language designers decided when they designed this mechanism.  You'd have to ask them if you want to know why.  There is no resource named `/pkg/readme.txt`, only `pkg/readme.txt`

Answer (score 2):

Class's getResource() - documentation states the difference:

> This method delegates the call to its class loader, after making these
>   changes to the resource name: if the resource name starts with "/", it
>   is unchanged; otherwise, the package name is prepended to the resource
>   name after converting "." to "/". If this object was loaded by the
>   bootstrap loader, the call is delegated to
>   ClassLoader.getSystemResource.

[What is the difference between Class.getResource() and ClassLoader.getResource()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608795/what-is-the-difference-between-class-getresource-and-classloader-getresource)

Comment: thanks. I'm not asking the diff between Class.getResource() and ClassLoader one. I just want to know why ClassLoader.getResource does not work for a resource name starts with a leading slash.