# Set relative path for files to read with BufferedReader

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader

I have an app, that needs to read files line by line. I'm using the following code and it's ok.

```
public ArrayList <String[]> LoadServersFile(String filename){
BufferedReader br=null;
ArrayList <String> result = new ArrayList();
try {
    String sCurrentLine;
    InputStreamReader reader =  new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/"+filename));
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

    while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        result.add(sCurrentLine);
    }
    br.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(FilesIO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(FilesIO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
return result;
```

}

But after compiling project and launching it, `br.readLine()` is always null. Setting `"/file.txt"` and putting this file to C:/ disk fixes the bug, but i need this file to be in folder with my .jar file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get your file using the getResourceAsStream method:

```
InputStreamReader reader =  new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/file.txt"));
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be without the `/`?

Comment: @Ben No because we're are not using the classloader. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608795/what-is-the-difference-between-class-getresource-and-classloader-getresource

Comment: @TheEwook It throws me NullException when i'm trying to create reader. And change it to (reader) instead of (isReader)

Comment: @crzbt My bad indeed ;) I modify my answer

Comment: @TheEwook but still it didn't work for me, throws `NullPointerException`. Updated my code..

Comment: @crzbt Can you try without the slash as Ben suggested? It works fine for me with the slash but a simple test does no harm ;)

Comment: @TheEwook Same result for both ways