# Failing to load properties file from the same package in Java

Tags: java, io, classloader, inputstream

I have a package located at `com.foo.bar`. Inside this package I have a `config.properties` file, and a `Test.java` class. I'm trying to simply load the properties file into an input stream. I have tried this:

```
InputStream is = Test.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
System.out.println("stream: " +  is );
```

And also:

```
String path = "com.foo.bar.config.properties";
InputStream is = Test.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path);
System.out.println("stream: " +  is );
```

In both cases, I get:

```
stream: null
```

as the value. No exception is thrown.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `com.foo.bar.config.properties` is *not* a path. Try providing the absolute path

Comment: It works for me with `com/foo/bar/config.properties` so maybe you have a problem elsewhere

Comment: @morgano yes, that worked. previously my `resources` directory was not added to the pom.xml, so it wasn't being compiled into the jar. adding it to pom fixed it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Class.getResource() and ClassLoader.getResource()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608795/what-is-the-difference-between-class-getresource-and-classloader-getresource)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with this:

```
InputStream is = Test.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("com/foo/bar/config.properties");
```

important to mention: don't use a '/' at the beginning (it's a commont mistake)

Comment: that worked, but since they're in the same package, shouldn't just `config.properties` work too?

Comment: @ClickUpvote the parameter for `getResourceAsStream(String id)`  is an identifier rather than a file path, so your resource (your properties file) has the identifier `com/foo/bar/config.properties`

Comment: @that's why you don't use a '/' at the beginning :-)