# Displaying an image in java within the project

Tags: java, image, file, user-interface

I am trying to make a few different jpgs appear on a GUI I am working on.  Originally, I was just referencing the file on my computer but I now want to put the jpgs into my project folder and reference them from there.  I was looking up how to do this online and I have gotten this far:

```
        BufferedImage myPicture = null;
    try {
        myPicture = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/HIOLogo.jpg"));
    } catch (IOException e1) {

        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    JLabel headerImage = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myPicture));

    headerImage.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 200);
    this.add(headerImage);
}
```

However, I am not sure where I should be putting the HIOLogo.jpg file within my project? Right now I just dragged the file straight into the project folder. When I run this I get an IllegalArgumentException.

Answer (score 0):

Is your file in the root folder?

for example if the file is in `src` folder the path should be `"/src/HIOLogo.jpg"`

If it's in folder outside `src` (root folder) then your path is right

so,

If the path is relative to the root of the classpath (specified by the leading /).

```
ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/path/to/resource"));
```

else if the path is relative to the root of the classpath (specified by the leading /).

```
ImageIO.read(new File("path/to/resource");
```

the path is relative to the root of the classpath (specified by the leading /).

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608795/what-is-the-difference-between-class-getresource-and-classloader-getresource/6608848#6608848)

Comment: Originally my file was in the root folder and I was using the getClass().getResource("/HIOLogo.jpg") and that is when I was getting the illegal argument exception.  Which I believe based on what you said I had the right path? So I am wondering if I am missing something else.  I also tried the new File("/HIOLogo.jpg") and that gave me an IIoexception