# forward slash in file path causing issues. File contents are not read. Gives "The system cannot find the path specified." error

Tags: java, file, separator

How to handle forward slash in file path. My requirement is to read the contents of a csv file. But giving something like

`String fileName = "MyNewFile.csv"` is converting `/` to `\`.
My operating system is Windows. I am using RAD IDE. 
Using `File.Separator` didn't help. Giving me a `The system cannot find the path specified.` error.

Tried this:

```
InputStream is = SampleClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("MyNewFile.csv");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

And this:

The moment I try to escape `/` as `\/` IDE shows me a compilation error  `Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )`

Tried moving the file directly under the project(moved it out from src folder) and changed the code as `br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));` 
But still seeing `The system cannot find the file specified.` error

Can anyone please help ???

Comment: What language are you programming in?  Java?  If so edit your question to have the appropriate tag.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "causing issues"? What exactly isn't working as expected?

Comment: Try escaping it using \ as \/src\/MyNewFile.csv

Comment: What is your exact issue? What do you expect, what do you get? For sure, `String fileName = "/src/MyNewFile.csv"` will **not** convert anything - how did you prove this assumption? Also, make sure that you understand the different flavours of resource loading: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6608848/1611055

Comment: Especially, note that ClassLoader resource paths are always absolute - there is no need to use a leading slash, and in certain situations it can be even wrong

Comment: Use `SampleClass.class.getResourceAsStream("MyNewFile.csv")`. If you call `.getResourceAsStream(...)` on a `ClassLoader` it expects the full path.

Comment: Even under Windows a slash inside a file or directory name is problematic. Maybe a `File.listFiles` with a file name filter might be a hack.

Comment: This has nothing to do with slashes. Forward slashes will always work and there is no reason to use backslashes. The problem is because `Class.getResourceAsStream()` accepts relative paths and `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()` only accepts absolute paths.

Answer (score 0):

```
               SampleClass.class
                .getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
                        "com/xyz/abc/" + MyNewFile.csv);
```

You can use the above give package name where the where the csv is located

Comment: So "MyNewFile.csv" is what? A variable or something?

Comment: MyNewFile.csv is the name of the file. I have comma separated contents in this file.

Answer (score 0):

Placing the file in a temporary directory outside my project solved the issue.
Below is how I am reading it. But this is just a temporary solution

`br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("c:\\temp\\MyNewFile.csv"));`

But I would still need to know how to read the contents if it is under the project