# Display an image in java

Tags: java, image, swing, embedded-resource, illegalargumentexception

```
public void loadStdImage() throws IOException
{
    Image image = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("/Resources/Images/Student/Capture.png"));  //Line 350
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
    JLabel lblImage = new JLabel(icon);
    lblImage.setIcon(icon);
    lblImage.setBounds(753, 50, 149, 171);
    add(lblImage);
}
```

I tried many things... but nothing works out. Continuously showing the following run-time error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at View.Student.loadStdImage(Student.java:350)
```

Project folder structure is:

[image: Project Explorer view in Eclipse for a project]

Comment: Check the path of the named resource and make sure it's (correct) and within reach of the classpath.  What IDE are you using?

Comment: double checked the path.... no joy, i'm usng ecllipse

Comment: So the `Resources` directory should either be in the project directory or the src directory. Remember the paths are case sensitive and typically `Resources` is called `resources` ;)

Comment: The Resources directory is in the same level as src directory.... mine 'Resources'

Comment: The only reason you would get a `null` input, is because the resource doesn't exist at the location you are specifying (or the spelling/case is wrong)

Comment: Spelling is right... I double checked it again...

Comment: Do a new build (clean and build if possible), export the project as a Jar, unzip the Jar and verify that the images you are looking for are where you expect them to be within the Jar

Comment: Thank you very much, I got the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have standard Eclipse project:

[image: Eclipse project]

and my test class looks like (minimal):

```
package q34460547;

import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class LoadTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new LoadTest().loadStdImage();
    }

    public void loadStdImage() throws IOException {
        Image image = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("/ScreenShot005.png"));
    }

}
```

and now, when I used

```
ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("/ScreenShot005.png"));
```

image is loaded from res so called source folder in Eclipse.

When I used

```
ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("ScreenShot005.png"));
```

image s loaded from the folder in which LoadTest.java file is (to be precise it is also compiled to same folder - in Eclipse it's bin).

You can find more info for example here - [What is the difference between Class.getResource() and ClassLoader.getResource()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608795/what-is-the-difference-between-class-getresource-and-classloader-getresource)

**edit:**

The image has to be on classpath (when using `Class.getResource`), that's why it was not loaded from `Resources` folder. There are two options, use another version of `ImageIO.read()` or make your `Resources` folder a source folder:

[image: Project properties - source folders in Eclipse]

Comment: it's working when the image is in the same folder as the .java class. But when the image is in the Resource folder (Find the file hierachy in this link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9bLkMQp6h6SX09nNFdUeklNZzA/view?usp=sharing)                                                                                  I suggest the code should be as like this: ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("/Resources/Images/Student/Capture.PNG"));                                                                                 But i'm getting a ' java.lang.IllegalArgumentException'

Comment: Notice the difference in folder icon for my `src` (same as your `src`) or my `img`, but your `Resources` folder has different icon - see the edit ;-) Please edit your question and add the picture there, it might help others in future ;-)