# Maven Resources Error in JUnit

Tags: maven

I have a simple Maven project where in one of my test, I would like to load a resource as a csv file from the resources folder. The resources folder is made available under src/test/resources

When I run the following code snippet:

```
URL url = getClass()
        .getClassLoader()
        .getResource("/myData.csv");
System.out.println(this.getClass().getResource("."));
System.out.print(url); // this gives null
```

I get a null for the url! Here is my build file:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.csv</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${target.jdk}</source>
                <target>${target.jdk}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Why is this not working? I'm on IntelliJ!

Comment: Remove completely your `<resources>` block, you don't need it. Second, you should use an `InputStream`: `getClass().getResourceAsStream(/myData.csv)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When loading resources via ClassLoader (as opposed to Class), you don't need to use absolute URLs, so just remove the leading slash `/`.

For details, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6608848/2492865

Comment: Also note that by default Maven includes everything under `src/main/resources` as resources and `src/test/resources` as test resources (only available during test and integration-test phases. You're overriding main resources to point to test resources, which is highly suspicious.