# Constants in Kotlin Spek Tests

Tags: kotlin, spek

I want to add some constants to my Spek test to hold the filenames of some resource files that the tests will access like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42739807/how-to-read-a-text-file-from-resources-in-kotlin).

What is the idiomatic way to do this?

In JUnit, I would declare a `static final` value.  But in Spek, I can't even use the typical kotlin idoim of a `companion object` to hold them as Spek tests are objects themselves, which can't have companions.  I can't even mark them as `const` as I get the error "Modifier 'const' is not applicable to 'local variable'.

So is there any better or more preferred way than this:

```
object MyTest : Spek({
   val SAMPLE_GRAPH_FILENAME1 = "sample_graph1.png"
   val SAMPLE_GRAPH_FILENAME2 = "sample_graph2.png"
   val SAMPLE_OTHER_FILENAME = "sample_data.txt"

   // test code
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place the constants inside the body of this object, although then you'd have to prefix them with the name of the object to access them:

```
object MyTest : Spek({

    println(MyTest.SAMPLE_GRAPH_FILENAME1)

}) {
    const val SAMPLE_GRAPH_FILENAME1 = "sample_graph1.png"
}
```

Alternatively, you could have another object hold these constants, or just make them package (or file, with `private`) scoped:

```
const val SAMPLE_GRAPH_FILENAME1 = "sample_graph1.png"

object MyTest : Spek({

    println(SAMPLE_GRAPH_FILENAME1)

})
```

Comment: Either would work, as would leaving them as is.  But which is preferred, and why?

Comment: If you can put it somewhere where it can be a `const`, it'll be inlined for a small performance improvement. Otherwise - it's your code, use whichever form looks good for your eyes. There's no significant difference, it's just a matter of organization.