# Why i cant read json file rom resource folder with Kotlin?

Tags: json, kotlin

im trying to read from my json file, i had it in root, but when i package to jar, the file dont come with. Now i put the json file in "resource" folder.

My code:

```
@Component
class DefaultData {

@Autowired
private lateinit var gameOfThronesService: GameOfThronesService

@PostConstruct
fun initializeDefault() {
    val reader = JsonReader(FileReader("game-of-thrones.json"))
    val gameofthronesCharacters: List<GameOfThronesDto> = Gson().fromJson(reader, object : TypeToken<List<GameOfThronesDto>>() {}.type)

    println("-----> JSON Data <-----")
    gameofthronesCharacters.forEach{ println(it) }

    gameOfThronesService.createCharactersFromJson(gameofthronesCharacters)
}
}
```

This worked when i had the json file in root, but it cant find it in "resource" folder, how to solve this?

I also tried: [How to read a text file from resources in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42739807/how-to-read-a-text-file-from-resources-in-kotlin)

Then i get this following error:

```
(File name too long)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at com.ahmmud16.gameofthrones.util.DefaultData.initializeDefault(DefaultData.kt:24) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:309) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
... 18 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a text file from resources in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42739807/how-to-read-a-text-file-from-resources-in-kotlin)

Comment: it dosent work, when i tried it, it says that file is too long .. ?

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: I updated the question with the error log

Comment: Hm, that's strange. Can you show the code you tried after looking at the above link?

Comment: val fileContent = this::class.java.classLoader.getResource("game-of-thrones.json").readText()

        val reader = JsonReader(FileReader(fileContent))

Comment: Right, now it makes sense. You are passing the whole file contents as if it was the file name.

Comment: Ok.. ? But how can i pass the file to JsonReader ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To read a file from the resources folder, you should be following this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42739807/how-to-read-a-text-file-from-resources-in-kotlin). You tried it, but not in the correct way.

When doing this:
`val fileContent = this::class.java.classLoader.getResource("game-of-thrones.json").readText()`, you are reading the contents of the file. You are then passing the whole file content to `FileReader` as if it was the file name (that's why you're getting a `File name too long` error).

From what I'm seeing in the Gson documentation, you can skip the creating of a `JsonReader` completely, and pass a `String` to `fromJson()`.

Can you try the following:

```
@Component
class DefaultData {

@Autowired
private lateinit var gameOfThronesService: GameOfThronesService

@PostConstruct
fun initializeDefault() {
    val fileContent = this::class.java.classLoader.getResource("game-of-thrones.json").readText()

    val gameofthronesCharacters: List<GameOfThronesDto> = Gson().fromJson(fileContent, object : TypeToken<List<GameOfThronesDto>>() {}.type)

    println("-----> JSON Data <-----")
    gameofthronesCharacters.forEach{ println(it) }

    gameOfThronesService.createCharactersFromJson(gameofthronesCharacters)
}
}
```

Comment: Thanx a lot! :)