# Getting the path of a folder through a Kotlin module in React Native

Tags: react-native, kotlin

I have a rather difficult question (I think ;))

I have a folder, and all its contents are taken together for model creation. This is happening in an Kotlin module in a React Native (CLI) project. I tried all sorts of absolute paths but it keeps giving me the error that I can't find the files.

I now tried to put it in an 'assets' folder that is on the level of main like so:

[Android structure within react native](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3iWB.png)

I found all kinds of answers on stackoverflow, but they all refer to files not directories.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Maybe you can add the links to the other question for more context of the issue!

Comment: This is a bit similar i think:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42739807/how-to-read-a-text-file-from-resources-in-kotlin