# Ktor dynamic file path

Tags: json, file, kotlin, path, ktor

I have a function that needs to load a json file, on the local server I can load using an absolute path, my question is how to program this path to work with me packaging the JAR file.

```
val serviceAccount = FileInputStream("C:/Users/Alan/Desktop/template-fullstack-ktor/src/backendMain/resources/firebase.json")
```

I believe that I need to create a dynamic path to the resource folder. But I'm a beginner and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42739807/how-to-read-a-text-file-from-resources-in-kotlin

Answer (score 3):

You can use anonymous object to get its class and then the class loader:

```
object {}.javaClass.classLoader.getResource("firebase.json")
```