# Measure JavaFX 8 Text Width Without com.sun.tk package

Tags: java, javafx

In JavaFX 8 and Java JDK 8, I used the `com.sun.javafx.tk.FontMetrics` class to compute text width. However, with the release of Java 9 and Project Jigsaw, the package is no longer visible.

Here is an example of the former methods I used:

```
FontLoader fl = Toolkit.getToolkit().getFontLoader();
FontMetrics fontMetrics = fl.getFontMetrics(font);
int textWidth = (int) fontMetrics.computeStringWidth(text);
int textHeight = (int) fontMetrics.getLineHeight();
```

What I need is a way to compute a String's width by providing a JavaFX Font (`javafx.scene.text.Font`). I would prefer not using AWT components to measure text width.

Comment: Can't you open/export the module? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46483226/1803551).

Comment: I tried doing opens {com.sun.javafx.tk} in my module info, but it is saying the module can't be found. The error message is specifically "Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Package com.sun.javafx.tk not found in module"