# I got a javafx.fxml.LoadException on a button

Tags: java, openjfx

I didn't get Scene Builder Code running. I started with OpenJDK 11 and OpenJFX 11. The code is adopted from JAVA8 Example (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uPm1n-cyupU ).

I added a package name, needed for module-info. I added a fx:controller="myfx.MyController". I tried it with fx:root and different names, also without anything , i still got constructLoadException, with botton and text field a javafx.fxml.LoadException

Main.java

```
package myfx;
import java.net.URL;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
        URL url = classLoader.getResource("Sample.fxml");
        System.out.println(url);
        Pane mainPane = (Pane) FXMLLoader.load(url);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(mainPane));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

MyController.java

```
package myfx;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class MyController {

    @FXML
    private TextField tf_name;

    @FXML
    void onSubmitClick(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println(tf_name.getText());
    }

}
```

Sample.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="myfx.MyController">
   <children>
      <Button layoutX="287.0" layoutY="158.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onSubmitClick" text="Submit" />
      <Label layoutX="140.0" layoutY="125.0" text="Name:" />
      <TextField fx:id="tf_name" layoutX="192.0" layoutY="121.0" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

module-info.java

```
module myfx {
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.controls;
    exports myfx;
}
```

Console

```
file:/D:/Users/v.sonntag/Documents/eclipse/eclipse-workspace/myfx/bin/Sample.fxml
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/D:/Users/v.sonntag/Documents/eclipse/eclipse-workspace/myfx/bin/Sample.fxml:10

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2625)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2603)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3237)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3194)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3163)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3136)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3106)
    at myfx/myfx.Main.start(Main.java:21)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make void myfx.MyController.onSubmitClick(javafx.event.ActionEvent) accessible: module myfx does not "opens myfx" to module javafx.fxml
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:340)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:280)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:198)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:192)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerAccessor.addAccessibleMethods(FXMLLoader.java:3515)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerAccessor.access$4000(FXMLLoader.java:3328)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerAccessor$1.run(FXMLLoader.java:3447)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerAccessor$1.run(FXMLLoader.java:3440)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerAccessor.addAccessibleMembers(FXMLLoader.java:3439)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerAccessor.getControllerMethods(FXMLLoader.java:3399)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.getControllerMethodHandle(FXMLLoader.java:570)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processEventHandlerAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:607)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:778)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2838)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2557)
    ... 17 more
Exception running application myfx.Main
```

Comment: Please include the entire stack trace in your question.

Comment: I don't hava java9 to test it, but with module you have to "open" your classes to make them accessible. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46482364/what-is-an-open-module-in-java-9-and-how-to-use-it  try to  add "opens myfx;" after "export myfx;" in your module-info.java

Comment: this is working, thy, so simple :-o