# Intellij IDEA - problem with JavaFX compilation

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx-11

I've reinstall my OS from Win7 to 10. After reinstalling Intellij IDEA + Corretto_11 + JavaFX libary I cannot compile programa that was working.

I'm quite green in Java, so i don't know hot to approche the problem.

Project set to Correto_11, language level 11, and FX libary added to module.

Even code from Course does not compile.

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper (in unnamed module @0x3a0bd002) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.util.Utils (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.util to unnamed module @0x3a0bd002
    at com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper.<clinit>(FXMLLoaderHelper.java:38)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.<clinit>(FXMLLoader.java:2056)
    at main.Main.start(Main.java:18)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application main.Main

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Edit:

After adding module I have following error:

```
"C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk11.0.7_10\bin\java.exe" --add-modules javafx.base,javafx.graphics --add-reads javafx.base=ALL-UNNAMED --add-reads javafx.graphics=ALL-UNNAMED "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=50795:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -p C:\Users\Sebastian\Documents\javafx_11\lib\javafx.base.jar;C:\Users\Sebastian\Documents\javafx_11\lib\javafx.graphics.jar;C:\Users\Sebastian\Desktop\JavaProjects\JavaFX_ToDo\out\production\JavaFX_ToDo;C:\Users\Sebastian\Documents\javafx_11\lib\javafx-swt.jar;C:\Users\Sebastian\Documents\javafx_11\lib\javafx.controls.jar;C:\Users\Sebastian\Documents\javafx_11\lib\javafx.fxml.jar;C:\Users\Sebastian\Documents\javafx_11\lib\javafx.media.jar;C:\Users\Sebastian\Documents\javafx_11\lib\javafx.swing.jar;C:\Users\Sebastian\Documents\javafx_11\lib\javafx.web.jar -m JavaFX.ToDo/main.Main
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Error reading module: C:\Users\Sebastian\Desktop\JavaProjects\JavaFX_ToDo\out\production\JavaFX_ToDo
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Package JavaFX.ToDo not found in module

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Edit 2:

Project structure:
[image]

Edit 3: 
Adding how my module look like:

```
module JavaFX.ToDo {
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;

    opens JavaFX.ToDo;
}
```

Edit 4:

Adding main content:

```
package main;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import main.models.TaskData;

import java.io.IOException;



public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("mainwindow.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX: ToDo-App");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 900, 500));
        primaryStage.show();
    }




    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

    }
    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        try {
            TaskData.getInstance().storeTasks();

        } catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        try {
            TaskData.getInstance().loadTasks();

        } catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Or i can push all on my github.

https://github.com/s-osyra/JavaFX_ToDoList

Comment: If you have a module-info file, declare your module `open`. Maybe it's a reflection thing

Comment: If you don't have a module-info file, I would suggest making one. Also, you should give `--add-modules ALL-MODULE-PATH` (or just the modules you need, like javafx.fxml) as one of the jvm's options

Comment: This is the important part, I think: `javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.util to unnamed module @0x3a0bd002` (that unnamed module is yours). You could maybe fix that with `--add-exports` too, but that's probably not a good idea because it's hacky.

Comment: I've added, and there is following error:

Error occurred during initialization of boot layer

Comment: Your project structure would be helpful

Comment: You will need to post the contents of your `Main.java`

Comment: Its all in now. I'm trying to work with it but still im confused. Its more likly problem with configuration or depencities than with code.

Comment: You should probably name your module something like javafx_todo instead of JavaFx.ToDo. It's not the convention.

Comment: Also, `opens` is used for packages. `JavaFx.ToDo` is not a package, it's your module name

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46482364/what-is-an-open-module-in-java-9-and-how-to-use-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error happened because your module wasn't open, and the `javafx.fxml` module (specifically FXMLLoader) wanted to use reflection.

The second error's just because you're using `opens` incorectly. It's meant to open packages, not modules.

This is your module-info file now:

```
module JavaFX.ToDo {
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;

    opens JavaFX.ToDo; //Here's the error
}
```

This is incorrect, because you don't have a package called `JavaFX.ToDo`, it's your module name. To make your module open (so javafx.fxml can do reflective access operations), you need to declare your module `open` like this:

```
open module JavaFX.ToDo {
  ...
}
```

xor this:

```
module JavaFX.ToDo {
  ...
  opens main; //This is where Main.java is, and where you use FXMLLoader
}
```

If you want it to be more secure, you could also declare it like this:

```
module JavaFX.ToDo {
  requires javafx.fxml;
  opens main to javafx.fxml; //Only fxml has reflective access to your package now
}
```

I would suggest reading [this article](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html) about Java 9's module system. Scroll down to where they talk about open modules.

Side note: Module names are lowercase by convention. You probably want something like `javafx_todo`

Comment: Thank you! Now it works. I'm just wondering, why previusly it worked, and now not.

Comment: @ago Yes it is! But I'm just not sure why it stop working after system re-instalation.

Comment: Yes. It was all the same. I've just reinstalled OS and it stoped working. Even, when I try to use code from course on Udemy. I added libary the same way.

Comment: Did you have Java 9+ or Java 8- before you reinstalled your OS?

Comment: Java 11 corretto in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this as follows in IntelliJ:
Run -> Edit configuration -> Configuration tab -> add following in VM options:
--module-path c:\javafx-sdk-14.0.1\lib --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml