# TestNG, JavaFX Intellij An error occurred while instantiating class, Unable to make public <test class> accessible

Tags: javafx, testng, fxml, rest-assured

I tried to call the test class programmatically and follow the instructor in the TestNG docs. When i called it in Eclipse, it worked, but when i switch to Intellij to be more convenient to use JavaFX so that i can make a UI program, it doesn't work and show this error.
This is my test call class

```
        

package com.vinh.testing.CallTest;

import org.testng.TestListenerAdapter;
import org.testng.TestNG;

import tests.LogOutTest;

public class TestLogOutCall {
    public void callLogOutTest() {

        TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
        TestNG testng = new TestNG();
        testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { LogOutTest.class });
        testng.addListener(tla);
        testng.run();

    }
}
```

and this is my test class

```
        
package tests;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.*;
import static org.testng.Assert.assertNotEquals;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;
import io.restassured.response.Response;

public class LogOutTest {

    String ACCESS_TOKEN = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC9hdWN0aW9uLWFwcDMuaGVyb2t1YXBwLmNvbVwvYXBpXC9sb2dpbiIsImlhdCI6MTY1NTUzNzg2OSwiZXhwIjoxNjU1ODk3ODY5LCJuYmYiOjE2NTU1Mzc4NjksImp0aSI6InJuejdrMHhSQmNUTHB2TnkiLCJzdWIiOjY1LCJwcnYiOiIyM2JkNWM4OTQ5ZjYwMGFkYjM5ZTcwMWM0MDA4NzJkYjdhNTk3NmY3In0.sX-pWrwDyGfCIhlqy_1huxTt3GSElXrQtnpKV53q4BM";
    @Test
    public void Test01() {

        baseURI = "https://auction-app3.herokuapp.com/api";

        Response response = given().
                header("Authorization", "bearer" + ACCESS_TOKEN).
                contentType("application/json").
                when().
                post("/logout");
        response.then().statusCode(200);
        System.out.println(response.getBody().asString());
        JsonPath jpath = response.jsonPath();
        int code = jpath.getInt("code");
        System.out.println(code);
        assertNotEquals(code, 1000);

    }

}
```

and then i met this

```
C:\Users\Lenovo\.jdks\openjdk-18.0.1.1\bin\java.exe "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=50009:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\18\javafx-controls-18.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\18\javafx-graphics-18.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-base\18\javafx-base-18.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-fxml\18\javafx-fxml-18.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\apache\groovy\groovy\4.0.1\groovy-4.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\apache\groovy\groovy-xml\4.0.1\groovy-xml-4.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.5.13\httpclient-4.5.13.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.4.13\httpcore-4.4.13.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.2\commons-logging-1.2.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.11\commons-codec-1.11.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpmime\4.5.13\httpmime-4.5.13.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest\2.1\hamcrest-2.1.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\ccil\cowan\tagsoup\tagsoup\1.2.1\tagsoup-1.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\apache\groovy\groovy-json\4.0.1\groovy-json-4.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\io\rest-assured\rest-assured-common\5.1.1\rest-assured-common-5.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\io\rest-assured\xml-path\5.1.1\xml-path-5.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\xml-apis\xml-apis\1.4.01\xml-apis-1.4.01.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\3.0.2\jsr305-3.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.36\slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\com\beust\jcommander\1.82\jcommander-1.82.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\webjars\jquery\3.6.0\jquery-3.6.0.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.10\junit-4.10.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.1\hamcrest-core-1.1.jar -p D:\Testing\target\classes;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\testng\testng\7.6.0\testng-7.6.0.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-base\18\javafx-base-18-win.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.11\commons-lang3-3.11.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-fxml\18\javafx-fxml-18-win.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\io\rest-assured\json-path\5.1.1\json-path-5.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\io\rest-assured\rest-assured\5.1.1\rest-assured-5.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\18\javafx-graphics-18-win.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\com\googlecode\json-simple\json-simple\1.1.1\json-simple-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\18\javafx-controls-18-win.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\controlsfx\controlsfx\11.1.1\controlsfx-11.1.1.jar -m com.vinh.testing/com.vinh.testing.AutomationTesting
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml@18/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1857)
    at javafx.fxml@18/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1724)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base@18/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@18/javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3586)
    at javafx.graphics@18/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3890)
    at javafx.graphics@18/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1874)
    at javafx.graphics@18/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2607)
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:551)
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:119)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml@18/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:84)
    at javafx.fxml@18/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1854)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.testng.TestNGException: 
An error occurred while instantiating class tests.LoginTest: Unable to make public tests.LoginTest() accessible: module com.vinh.testing does not "exports tests" to module org.testng
    at org.testng@7.6.0/org.testng.internal.objects.SimpleObjectDispenser.createInstance(SimpleObjectDispenser.java:99)
    at org.testng@7.6.0/org.testng.internal.objects.SimpleObjectDispenser.dispense(SimpleObjectDispenser.java:40)
    at org.testng@7.6.0/org.testng.internal.objects.GuiceBasedObjectDispenser.dispense(GuiceBasedObjectDispenser.java:28)
    at org.testng@7.6.0/org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:106)
    at org.testng@7.6.0/org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:136)
    at org.testng@7.6.0/org.testng.TestClass.getInstances(TestClass.java:129)
    at org.testng@7.6.0/org.testng.TestClass.initTestClassesAndInstances(TestClass.java:109)
    at org.testng@7.6.0/org.testng.TestClass.init(TestClass.java:101)
    at org.testng@7.6.0/org.testng.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:66)
    at org.testng@7.6.0/org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:463)
    at org.testng@7.6.0/org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:335)
    at org.testng@7.6.0/org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:288)
    at org.testng@7.6.0/org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:178)
    at org.testng@7.6.0/org.testng.SuiteRunner$DefaultTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:639)
    at org.testng@7.6.0/org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:225)
    at org.testng@7.6.0/org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:115)
    at org.testng@7.6.0/org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1349)
    at org.testng@7.6.0/org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1325)
    at org.testng@7.6.0/org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1167)
    at org.testng@7.6.0/org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1099)
    at org.testng@7.6.0/org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1067)
    at com.vinh.testing/com.vinh.testing.CallTest.TestLoginCall.CallTestLogin(TestLoginCall.java:16)
    at com.vinh.testing/com.vinh.testing.Controller.Test(Controller.java:63)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make public tests.LoginTest() accessible: module com.vinh.testing does not "exports tests" to module org.testng
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.checkCanSetAccessible(Constructor.java:191)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.setAccessible(Constructor.java:184)
    at org.testng@7.6.0/org.testng.internal.objects.SimpleObjectDispenser.instantiateUsingDefaultConstructor(SimpleObjectDispenser.java:177)
    at org.testng@7.6.0/org.testng.internal.objects.SimpleObjectDispenser.createInstance(SimpleObjectDispenser.java:87)
    ... 59 more
```

Im new to TestNG, pls help me.

Comment: This is a modularity issue involving test code similar to this [issue using testfx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72723818/testfx-error-unit-test-package-is-not-exported-to-org-testfx-junit5).   You could read the comments there and see if anything helps in your situation.

Comment: Are you sure you need to modularize your tests with `module com.vinh.testing`, or can you delete that module?

Comment: Why is the fxml loader loading your test class? That is a weird setup.

Comment: You could do what the error message says:  `module com.vinh.testing does not "exports tests" to module org.testng`

Comment: Thank you so much bro, when i delete module testing it works. Sincerely thank yo.