# getResourceAsStream returns null for an existing file

Tags: java, file, io, resources

I try to load a resource file as a stream:

```
public static InputStream getClientSecretStream() {
    return ClientSecretsUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/Me/my_txt.json");
}
```

I have the file under:

`"/src/main/resources/Me/my_txt.json"`

But `.getResourceAsStream("/Me/my_txt.json");` returns null

and `.getResourceAsStream("my_txt.json");` returns null as well

what should I check for?

Comment: What's the structure of your project? How do you build it? How do you run it?

Comment: `"/src/main/resources/Me/my_txt.json"` I run the java code via tomcat project in intelij

Comment: Is it a Maven project? Have you imported it as a Maven project in IntelliJ? Is the src/main/resources folder marked as a Resources Root in IntelliJ?

Comment: What does the Javadoc of that method say about how it resolves the resource name?

Comment: No maven. gradle. but it all works as I run it in intliji tomcat config.

Comment: Then have you imported it as a gradle project? Is the src/main/resources folder marked as a Resources Root in IntelliJ? Why did you add a leading "/", which should not be there?

Comment: yes, it's marked as resources. I added the `/` as a try. doesn't work with or without

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Class.getResource() and ClassLoader.getResource()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608795/what-is-the-difference-between-class-getresource-and-classloader-getresource)

Answer (score 0):

- A class loader has absolute paths, without heading slash.
- A class.getResource starts at the package directory path of that class when a relative path, or needs a starting slash for absolute paths.

So:

```
return ClientSecretsUtils.class.getClassLoader()
           .getResourceAsStream("Me/my_txt.json");
return ClientSecretsUtils.class.getResourceAsStream("/Me/my_txt.json");
```

Where ClientSecretsUtil is in the same jar.

Look in the jar (is in zip format), and check the path. It must be **case sensitive**.

Your directory convention adheres to the maven build infrastructure, so my guess is maybe an accidental my_txt.json.txt or such.