# Ressources can't be found in maven build

Tags: java, maven

I wanted to migrate my local prototype to a maven build and start getting productive. But unfortunately when calling

```
loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("views/TaskWindow.fxml"));
```

On runtime it seems that maven doenst find the ressource xmls. 
I tryed "TaksWindow.xml", "../views/TaksWindow.xml" "views/TaskWindow.xml" and "/views/TaksWindow.xml" but somehow it always gives me "no location set" error.

My project structure looks like this:

[image]

Any ideas why?

Comment: First maven has nothing to do with finding resources..Your code does not correctly find the resources. The question is where have you located the resources you are trying to load?

Comment: edited the structure in.

Comment: Ah ok..than you have to use `getClass().getResource("/views/TaskWindow.fxml")´. The leading slash is important otherwise the loading is realtive to the class in which you are using this....

Comment: beautiful!! I thought i tryed that alread... must have slipped a class and then crashed the whole application...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path you specified is a relative path. Which means the classloader will look for a `views` folder at the location of the class (i. e. its package). You propably want to use an absolute path.

Try the following code, notice the leading `/`.

```
getClass().getResource("/views/TaskWindow.fxml")
```

For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6608848/7677308).