# How do I use a classloader to get inputstream on a model.zip file where the zip file is wrapped in a .jar file in classpath

Tags: java, classloader, jetty-9, jetty-8

**The issue:**

We have a jetty web-app, and in the application-code, I am trying to access a zip within a jar in classpath. Here's the jar in the libs folder:

```
/path/to/app/x.x.0-SNAPSHOT/apps/libs/my-model.jar
```

where ***my-model.jar*** is really just an empty folder with model.zip file inside it. If I extract this jar, I get ***johnsnow/mymodel.zip***

My application code tries to access this zip as:

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("johnsnow/mymodel.zip")
```

but of course, I don't get a proper handle to this resource and wind up getting a nullpointer exception. What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't I be able to access a file within a jar file in classpath using the `getClass().getResourceAsStream()` method?

**Footnote:**

Because model.zip was too large, we decided against shipping it with the code base. Thus we pushed it into a nexus repository, and reference the jar via a gradle compile dependency as follows:

```
compile "com.company.group.nlp:my-model:1.0@jar"
```

The fact that building the distribution pulls this jar, and puts it in apps/libs tells me that gradle does its part (of downloading the dependency to a classpath). The issue remains that I can't seem to find a way to access mymodel.zip inside my-model.jar

Comment: I think [an answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6608848/3284624) might help you

Comment: Put a `/` in front: `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/johnsnow/mymodel.zip")`

Comment: that seemed to work, guys !! thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a slash to the file path:

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/johnsnow/mymodel.zip");
```

It will tell java to start looking for the class from the root folder, not from the current class package.