# Application work on Eclipse, give problem as jar

Tags: java, properties, jsch

My little application works perfectly on Eclipse, instead give problems when I try to call its jar from command line. The problem looks like to reguard my resources folder where I put some properties file.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:*****************************\EasyDeployment\target\EasyDeployment-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!\ssh.properties
 (the syntax of the file name and the directory name or the value label it is not correct) // I translate this part that was in my native language
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at Configuration.PropertiesMenager.getAllKeys(PropertiesMenager.java:91)
        at GraphicInterface.SshChooser.initialize(SshChooser.java:101)
        at GraphicInterface.SshChooser.<init>(SshChooser.java:62)
        at GraphicInterface.SshChooser$1.run(SshChooser.java:49)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

my structure:

[image]

my references:

```
public final static String SSH_PROPERTIES = "ssh.properties";
    public final static String PORT_PROPERTIES = "port.properties" ;
    public final static String CMD_PROPERTIES = "cmd.properties" ;
    public final static String CONF_PROPERTIES = "configuration.properties";
```

example of a method that call these properties:

```
public String getPropertiyByKey(String key, String propFile) throws IOException {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        FileInputStream objFileInputStream = null;
        objClassLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        String result = "";
        try {
            System.out.println(propFile);
            objFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(objClassLoader.getResource(propFile).getFile());
            prop.load(objFileInputStream);
            result=prop.getProperty(key);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            objFileInputStream.close();
        }   
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: use getResourceAsStream() instead of getResource() with your class loader.

Comment: I will try now. I don't need the "getFile()" method so?
 the getResource takes a file, the getResourceAsStream a String

Comment: `objFileInputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFile)`

Comment: Wow my friend, it worked. How did you know, what is the explenation? If you want to put your comment as Answer I will close the ask!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always import files with `getResourceAsStream()` instead of `getResource()`

```
objFileInputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFile)
```

You can find an explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10597177/10712233)