# Getting a file as a resource on classpath

Tags: java, inputstream, keepass

I'm trying to read a keystore as a resource. Sample code below. The problem I'm running into is that inputStream remains null.

```
import java.io.InputStream;

import java.util.List;

import org.linguafranca.pwdb.kdbx.KdbxCreds;
import org.linguafranca.pwdb.kdbx.simple.SimpleDatabase;
import org.linguafranca.pwdb.kdbx.simple.SimpleEntry;
import org.linguafranca.pwdb.Credentials;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;



public class Security {

private static final String PATH = null;
private static final String KEYSTORE_PASSWORD = "admin";
static List<SimpleEntry> entries = null;

final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Security.class);

public Security(){


    //TODO: initialize security and it's passwords


}

public static void init(){

try {

        //InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(".keePass.kdbx");
        InputStream inputStream = Security.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("keePass.kdbx");

        // password credentials
        Credentials credentials = new KdbxCreds(KEYSTORE_PASSWORD.getBytes());

        SimpleDatabase database = SimpleDatabase.load(credentials, inputStream);
        // Jaxb implementation seems a lot faster than the DOM implementation
        // visit all groups and entries and list them to console
        entries = database.getRootGroup().getEntries();

    }catch(Exception exception){
        logger.error(exception);
    }

}
}
```

First I thought it's just a matter of path, however even though the file itself resides next to the classes, I can't load it.

[image]

Even if I use absolute path, result is the same.

What is the mistake I'm making?

Comment: Your file is in sources path. But is it in classpath? (Where compiled .class fires are) are you using maven?

Comment: That was indeed the issue, I haven't put the appropriate folder to the run configuration.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("...")` it tries to find the file in the root of classpath. Try to use:

```
Security.class.getResourceAsStream("keePass.kdbx");
```

In this case it will try to find the file in the same location as the `Security` class

See more [What is the difference between Class.getResource() and ClassLoader.getResource()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608795/what-is-the-difference-between-class-getresource-and-classloader-getresource)