# FXML loader can't find .fxml file in the project with modules

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, fxmlloader

I have a project with such structure:

[image]

I trying to load sample.fxml from the Main class using this code:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("../../submodule/src/java/sample.fxml"));
```

but it doesn't work. The sample.fxml file code is:

```
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>


<GridPane fx:controller="sample.Controller"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10"    vgap="10">
</GridPane>
```

The problem is that FXML loader can't find this location. How to solve it?

Comment: Move the FXML file into the _resources_ directory. Then using `getClass().getResource("/sample.fxml")` should work—assuming both modules end up on the classpath at runtime.

Comment: @Slaw Unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: Your project structure looks a bit strange. Is your main module a maven parent?

Comment: moduls or not: class.getResource(...) _does not_ support _".."_ - actually, I don't understand why everybody seems to assume that it does - just read the api doc and what do you _not_ see ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to follow the basic maven package structure, like this:

```
src
 |--main
      |--java
      |--resource (put your FXML file into this folder)
```

Then the following should work:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("sample.fxml"));
```

You can also put your FXML file into a subfolder:

```
... = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("layouts/sample.fxml"));
```

Here is a link showing the difference between `getClass().getResource()` vs `getClass.getClassLoader().getResource()`
(The difference is in relative vs absolute paths. If you always want to start from the `/resources` directory in a Maven project, you should use `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource()`.

[What is the difference between Class.getResource() and ClassLoader.getResource()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608795/what-is-the-difference-between-class-getresource-and-classloader-getresource)