# How to repair Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required. JavaFX

Tags: maven, javafx

Hello after adding maven to my JavaFX module got crash and can't find solve. I really tried a lot of solution from stackof but nothing working. In my start() method intellij can't find resource of my fxml file, it returning always null also when i created other fxml file in same directory. It's really weird situation because when i am use CTRL+Click on second.fxml intellij finding file correctly. Everything was working before maven.

Tried:

```
- getClass().getResource("second.fxml")
- getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("second.fxml")
- System.out.println("Test  = "+Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("second.fxml")); <- always null
- getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("src/java/sample/second.fxml")
And a lot of other combine with getClass().
```

Main Class

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("Test  = "+Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("second.fxml"));
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("second.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 800));
        primaryStage.show();

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

FXML class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            fx:controller="pl.zar.fx.Controller"
            prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0">

</AnchorPane>
```

Controller class

```
public class Controller {

@FXML
    public void onClickAddButton(ActionEvent event){}
}
```

And my Maven pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafxapp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies> <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency></dependencies>
</project>
```

Error code:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at pl.zar.fx.Main.start(Main.java:15)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application pl.zar.fx.Main
```

I expected return of my fxml template but getting NULL always.
EDIT project structure:
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nW9WB.png)

Comment: Show your project structure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Sedrick updated i added jpg with project structure

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to put your `fxml` files into the `resources` folder and use the following code to call them:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("second.fxml"));
```

The important thing here is that you need to move your `fxml` files into the resources folder. Otherwise it won't work.

Also documented in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55240355/9478795) answer.

Comment: I tried this solution, throws the same error also i tried put fxml to src to main to java to other package, gave full path, part path only fxml name etc but always return NULL

Answer (score 0):

Ok i solve it:
i moved fxml files to resources as you said and switch

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("second.fxml"));
```

to

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("second.fxml"));
```

Working good now, i don't know why i must use references to Main class. Before adding maven framework all was good.

Comment: please read the api doc of both class.getResource and classLoader.getResource: they differ in where they lookup the resource.