# Difference between getResource and getResourceAsStream?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a simple question: I am working on a JavaFX application and need a reference to a specific class. I looked my problem up on the Internet and found out that I had to use `getResourceAsStream` instead of `getResource`. I looked up both methods and only found one difference. The `getResourceAsStream` returns an `InputStream` and the `getResource` returns an `URL`. But what is the difference, why is the `InputStream` working for me and the `URL` not? I never really worked with `Stream`, any explanations are greatly appreciated.

`getResource(String name)`
`getResourceAsStream(String name)`

Comment: The resource URL may be packed into a jar file so you won't be able to resolve it; the stream already contains the data you're trying to access.

Comment: Both methods point work with the exact same resource. Using `clazz.getResource(p).openStream()` should have the same result as using `clazz.getResourceAsStream(p)`. If one is problematic and the other not, something else seems to be wrong with your code (provide a [mcve]). Perhaps you're using this with `FXMLLoader` and pass both values to the `load` method of a loader instance? In that case note that one of the methods is `static` and the other not so one of them uses the loader instance you created and the other one creates a new one. (Pass the url via loader constructor and call `load()`.)

Comment: ```FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();

        Parent root = fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("stochastik.fxml"));

        controller = fxmlLoader.getController();
        stage.setTitle("Stochastikrechner von Leon und Tom");```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add information (if it's an example make sure it's a [mre]).

Comment: "_I never really worked with `Stream` [...]_": If  by `Stream` you mean `java.util.stream.Stream`, then note that an `InputStream` is not a `Stream`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Class.getResource() and ClassLoader.getResource()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608795/what-is-the-difference-between-class-getresource-and-classloader-getresource)

Answer (score 0):

`getResource()` will work only if your WAR is exploded. In OpenShift, this is not the case so you should be using `getResourceAsStream()` to get that work.