# Why is the result inconsistent for loading a file from class vs. the classloader

Tags: java

I have this code

```
    InputStream stream1 = ResponseCreator.class.getResourceAsStream("version.properties");
    InputStream stream2 = ResponseCreator.class.getResourceAsStream("/version.properties");
    InputStream stream3 = ResponseCreator.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("version.properties");
    InputStream stream4 = ResponseCreator.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/version.properties");

    System.out.println("result1="+stream1);
    System.out.println("result2="+stream2);
    System.out.println("result3="+stream3);
    System.out.println("result4="+stream4);
```

and the results are...

```
result1=null
result2=java.io.BufferedInputStream@75412c2f
result3=java.io.BufferedInputStream@282ba1e
result4=null
```

That seems very odd and inconsistent and I even see posts saying stream1 is the way to go and that doesn't even work for me (eclipse IDE run, Intellij IDE run on MAC both yield the same)

I was running jdk8 and now I tried with 11 which is what we run now.  Here is the results..

```
INFO: Starting Development Server under java version=11.0.5
result1=null 
result2=sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection$JarURLInputStream@3b220bcb
result3=sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection$JarURLInputStream@2b95e48b
result4=null
```

Comment: Which version of java are you using?

Comment: @cse updated post.  we were using jdk8 and now 11.  It's odd the Stream changed...lol.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6608848/1031296) help with your question?

Comment: Did you **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`Class.getResourceAsStream(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) and [`ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-). It very clearly explains how they work, and why e.g. `stream1` is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javadoc of [`Class.getResourceAsStream(String name)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) says:

> - If the `name` begins with a `'/'` (`'\u002f'`), then the absolute name of the resource is the portion of the `name` following the `'/'`.
> - Otherwise, the absolute name is of the following form:
>
>   ```
>    modified_package_name/name
>   ```
>
>   Where the `modified_package_name` is the package name of this object with `'/'` substituted for `'.'` (`'\u002e'`).

So, if we assume that class `ResponseCreator` is in package `com.example` then:

```
// The following are the same, and returns resource "com/example/version.properties"
ResponseCreator.class.getResourceAsStream("version.properties")
ResponseCreator.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("com/example/version.properties")

// The following are the same, and returns resource "version.properties"
ResponseCreator.class.getResourceAsStream("/version.properties")
ResponseCreator.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("version.properties")

// The following returns null because resource names don't start with /
ResponseCreator.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/version.properties")
```

Since you only have resource `"version.properties"`, you get:

- `stream1` returns `null` (not found)
- `stream2` and `stream3` returns a stream for the resource
- `stream4` returns `null` (not found, aka invalid name)

There is nothing inconsistent about this. The methods do exactly what they are **documented** to do. It is entirely up to you to *read the documentation*, so you understand what the methods do, rather than attempting to guess how they work.