# What error am I making with the ClassLoader getResources?

Tags: java, junit, mocking, classloader

I have written the following code to test a method within my code. To create the s3Event, I have a json file but when I use the class loader I am always returned a null exception. It could be possible I have the absolute path incorrect? I have attached an image to show the file pathway layout in case this is the mistake.

```
@Test
@DisplayName("Testing the handleRequest")
void testTheHandleRequest() throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    File file = new File(Objects.requireNonNull(classLoader.getResource("s3Event.json")).toURI());

    S3Event s3Event = new ObjectMapper().readValue(file, S3Event.class);
    Context context = null;
    LambdaHandler lambdaHandler = new LambdaHandler();

    assertEquals ("Finished handleRequest()", lambdaHandler.handleRequest(s3Event, null));
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608795/what-is-the-difference-between-class-getresource-and-classloader-getresource?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: more ever I insist getResourceAsStream()  method for performance standpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem I could find is in the project structure. Maven supports the default **ClassLoader** resource behaviour for the default structure **`src/test/resources`**, whereas in your case the folder name is **`src/test/java/testResources`**, which requires additional configurations to be made either in POM or in program.

My project folder structure is given below,

[image]

```
@Test
@DisplayName("Testing on the classloader")
public void testOnClassLoader() throws URISyntaxException {
    ClassLoader cl = getClass().getClassLoader();

    File file = new File(Objects.requireNonNull(cl.getResource("sample.json").toURI()));

    if(file != null) {
        System.out.println("File found "+ file.getAbsolutePath());
        assertEquals(true, true);
    }       

}
```

**Output:**

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running JsonLoaderTest
File found ~\resource-access\target\test-classes\sample.json
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.139 sec

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  7.007 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-05-05T12:51:02+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Krish.Venkat - perfect answer! I'd changed the resources name and didn't realize the specific pathway was required by maven. Cheers.