# cannot find resource with maven, even with resource marked as root directory

Tags: java, maven, filenotfoundexception

[image: My project strrcture]

I am trying to read pws.csv in the resources directory with this line:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(App.class.getClass().getResourceAsStream("pws.csv")));
```

When I try to run it in IntelliJ or the comiled jar, I get a NullPointerExceptions, which I understand means that the file cannot be found. I also tried variations on the path like "/pws.csv" and "src/main/resources/pws.csv" and got the same error. My understanding is, that when using maven, "src/main/resources" is a special directory and intelliJ will recognize it, when searching for resources do I have to change some setting to achieve this or am I just stupid ?

Edit:
Listing of the jar:

[image: Listing of the jar]

Stacktrace of running that jar:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:167)
    at java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
    at com.kolan.Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

Comment: Can you please describe what: `For some reason it wont work,` means? Exception? does not work in IDE? Does not work on command line??

Comment: *i also tried variations on the path like "/pws.csv"* And that's the very one that ought to work.

Comment: @khmarbaise editet the Question to include the error. I am sorry.

Comment: @g00se sadly it did not, the very reason I am here

Comment: Please include the listing of the compiled jar: `jar tf foo-bar-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` *formatted as code*
*@khmarbaise editet the Question to include the error. I am sorry.* I don't see that edit...

Comment: Make it absolute (`/pws.csv`), not relative (without slash)! ...who knows where it otherwise resolves to!? (-> `/com/kolan/pws.csv`!?;)

Comment: ..and also expand `target/classes` (to verify csv inside)

Comment: And of course good old: [Class.getResource vs ClassLoader.getResource](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6608795/592355)

Comment: @xerx593 the .csv is under target/classes/com/ is that the correct directory here? Also I tried using the ClassLoader but I got the same result ( Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream )

Comment: *is that the correct directory here?* No. It should be one higher. But according to the gui tree, that shouldn't be happening

Comment: `com` is really strange(please clean build).

Comment: it's under classes now

Comment: Then it should work with /pws.csv. It's probably better to have at least one directory of the resource root though

Comment: Sadly it does not, i still get the same error when running the jar and the file via intelliJ

Comment: @g00se what exactly do you mean by that "It's probably better to have at least one directory of the resource root though" ?

Comment: Since you still haven't posted the listing I can't really say why. Don't worry about my remark about directories at the moment. That's not going to help immediately

Comment: I'm sorry, I added the output to the question

Comment: Please never post images of text. They are not searchable, we cannot copy-paste... Always copy-paste the text and format it properly.
But put that into practice right now by pasting the full stack trace of running the jar

Comment: Should be in the answer now

Comment: Had to leave. Back later

Comment: At this stage I'd probably need a link to your source

Answer (score 0):

Put pwc.csv in a folder that is on the classpath. And of course, double check your classpath setting.