# Usage of Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("system.properties")

Tags: java, file, classpath

In my web application, I have kept system.properties file in the web-inf/classes folder.

To Access that file's inputstream, I am using the code snippet below:

```
InputStream is = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_FILE)
```

Is there any other way to access that file?

Comment: Read the javadoc for each of those method calls.

Comment: @Skaffman Reading javadoc only gives is information about one by one method, I want the whole information of this line...

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve. Since you have a concise working method, why do you want another method? You could hard-code the location of the file, for example, but that's not a _good_ method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It simply means: Return the property file as `InputStream` from the `ClassLoader` the current thread of my application is running from (in loose english).

Comment: Is there any other way to access that file??

Comment: @SAM, what do you mean? Where is the file stored? Be descriptive first, and give me info needed in order for me to give you accurate answer.

Comment: I have got the link on stackoverflow itself:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676250/different-ways-of-loading-a-file-as-an-inputstream

Comment: @SAM, then I can't really answer your question, since the answer has already been answered already (read the upvoted post on your link).