# Java relative path for a Folder, not working with File

Tags: java, macos, file, relative-path, absolute-path

I am using a Mac and I am new to it. Here is my question:

There is a folder that I require to include as a File object in Java. When I try this:

```
File firefoxProfileFolder = new File("/Users/prime/work/dmall/selenium/src/test/resources/firefoxprofile");
```

It works fine. This code is located in file: `/Users/prime/work/dmall/selenium/src/test/java/com/dmall/utils/WebUtil.java`

But when I try this:

```
File firefoxProfileFolder = new File("../../../../resources/firefoxprofile");
```

I can not load the folder. So the relative path from this file to that folder seems not to work. So what should I do? What is it I am doing wrong?

I require to use the relative path because this code will be run from the server, on which I have no idea what the absoulte path will be.

Comment: That `.java` file is going to be compiled to a `.class` and run from somewhere else.

Comment: Please post a rough diagram of the directory structure.

Comment: @Singularity So what should I do?

Comment: You can not obtain the resource simply based on the package hierarchy of your Java source file, you can get resource at runtime via Classloader though. see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9111484/usage-of-thread-currentthread-getcontextclassloader-getresourceasstreamsys

Comment: @GavinXiong But this is not a property file it is a folder?

Comment: @KorayTugay When a java app is launched the command `java <class>` is run, the current directory of that command shell will be `./` for the app process. But still, hard-coding relative paths is no good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain the directory at runtime:

```
URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("relative to/classpath/resources/firefoxprofile");
File file = new File(url.getFile()); // the directory
....
```

Comment: I do not need a txt file, I need the folder itself.

Comment: Thank you. It is clear. Should I really use the string relative to/classpath/resources... as the parameter to the method? It did not work..

Comment: @KorayTugay No, it's just an example, depending on your package structure. It is noticeable that if you are using maven, the src/test/resources folder will not be packaged at runtime conventionally, you should put your resources into src/main/resources.

Answer (score 3):

It is most likely, that you have made a mistake in relative path. It should work.

For checking this, you can create new test directory using `new File('testDir').mkdirs()` and see - where Java will create this directory. Will it be in the expected place or somewhere else?

Comment: Hi, I guess the relative path is correct, but it does not work this way.

Comment: Do not *guess*, you should **check** this using mentioned method to be *sure*.

Answer (score 3):

You could use firefoxProfileFolder.getCanonicalPath() and check if it is the same path as 
    String s = new File("/Users/prime/work/dmall/selenium/src/test/resources/firefoxprofile").getCanonicalPath();
If it isn't the same path, your relative path is false...

Answer (score 2):

You actually need to use directory path considering current directory of the launcher script. I.e. your root directory is this script's directory.