# Selecting a file in another directory for a bufferedReader

Tags: java, directory, bufferedreader, fileinputstream

I have an initialization file (initialize.java) that pulls in data from fileInput.txt using a fileInputStream, but both of them are in different directories.

> ```
> Project/library/initialize.java
> Project/resources/text/fileInput.txt
> ```

my code in initialize.java is:

```
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("/resources/text/fileInput.txt");
```

But the file cannot be read. I've also tried

```
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("./resources/text/fileInput.txt");
```

But that didn't work too.

How can I access the txt file and what's the difference between using "./resources" and "/resources"?

Thanks for reading this.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys. I realized it was my big mistake but at least i learnt the "./" Directory stuff :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is huge. On [linux](/questions/tagged/linux)/[unix](/questions/tagged/unix)/[macos](/questions/tagged/macos) the path starting with / starts from root directory. The path starting with ./ or without starting from current application directory. Call

`System.out.println(new File("."). getAbsolutePath())` to check where you are?

Comment: Silly me.. I did the absolute path thing and found out it was actually Project/src/library and i had to do a "new FileInputStream("src/resources/...") thank you!!

Comment: Maybe the problem is that resources is your root folder in resources. So try [InputStream in = ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("/text/fileInput.txt")](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) or `InputStream in = ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("text/fileInput.txt")`, I've never known :). Now the root is your classpath root.

Answer (score 2):

FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("resources/text/fileInput.txt");

Tried this?

Answer (score 2):

`"./resources/text/fileInput.txt"` or `"resources/text/fileInput.txt"` works,
but `"/resources/text/fileInput.txt"` doesn't.

Note: This is valid if the folder named "resources" is located under the root directory of your project.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers suggest, the path you pass to FileInputStream depends on the OS and also if the path is a relative or an absolute path. Another way of reading the file is to use `Class.getResourceAsStream()` instead. e.g.

> InputStream is =
>   this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/text/fileInput.txt")

For the above to work, you need to have the parent folder of `/resources` in the classpath. For more information on how getResourceAsStream works, see [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676250/different-ways-of-loading-a-file-as-an-inputstream)