# Reading properties file outside jar

Tags: java, jar, runnable

I have my jar file and properties file in same location (C:\test). When I run the jar through script, it throws FileNotFound exception for the properties file. This runs perfectly through RAD. What am I doing wrong here. I tried other ways, like getting the path of the jar file, etc, but no luck there too.

Script:

```
@echo off
REM Eventually change directory to the program directory 
cd C:\test\
REM run the program
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe" -jar  "C:\test\test.jar"
```

Code to read properties file:

```
    private void loadProperties() throws IOException{

    appProperties = new Properties();
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream("./EDMSWS.properties");
    appProperties.load(in);
    in.close();
}
```

Manifest File:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./ commons-io-2.4.jar JSQLConnect.jar poi-3.11-201412
21.jar
Class-Path: .
Rsrc-Main-Class: com.example.xxx.xxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try use  **InputStream in = new FileInputStream("./EDMSWS");**

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\EDMSWS (The system cannot find the file specified.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679867/selecting-a-file-in-another-directory-for-a-bufferedreader