# How do I convert InputStream into a String?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, inputstream, bufferedreader

I tried this:

```
  InputStream file = Test.class.getResourceAsStream("highScore.txt");
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(file));
  String text;
  text = br.readLine();
  while (text!=null) {
    System.out.println (text);
  }
```

but I get `NullPointerException` error.

Comment: are you sure highScore.txt exists on your classpath?

Comment: Where exactly is the NPE thrown?

Comment: You mean where the error occurs? It occurs at   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(file));

Comment: Try adding a slash `/` to the resource name: `Test.class.getResourceAsStream("/highScore.txt");`

Comment: On which line are you getting a NullPointerException?

Answer (score 2):

The resource you're trying to read as an InputStream should exist on your Java Classpath. Otherwise `getResourceAsStream()` would return null, leading to `NullPointerException` when you try to create an `InputStreamReader` out of it. See [different-ways-of-loading-a-file-as-an-inputstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676250/different-ways-of-loading-a-file-as-an-inputstream) on how to read a resource.

Answer (score 2):

Try a simple file instead:

```
InputStream file = new FileInputStream("highScore.txt");
```

#### Edited

If you are having problems getting the path right, do this:

```
System.out.println(new File("highScore.txt").getAbsolutePath());
```

That will quickly tell you what the "current" directory is. You might find you need to use `"../highScore.txt"` if you need to go up one directory level, or `"/somedir/highScore.txt"` if you need to go down, etc.

I find printing the absolute path is the quickest way to resolve these kinds of problems.

Comment: The absolute path is C:\Users\Name\workspace\Test\highScore.txt which is exactly where I put it. Now what?

Comment: Then your `FileNotFoundException` has nothing to do with that file. Maybe there's somewhere else in your code that you're using a file that isn't there (cos this one is there)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one-liner for file-to-string

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerSample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
     //Z means: "The end of the input but for the final terminator, if any"
        String output = new Scanner(new File("file.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
        System.out.println("" + output);
    }
}
```

Comment: Forgot to give credit to Adam Bien for this one: http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/reading_a_file_into_a2