# Read Properties file in java

Tags: java, properties

How do I give absolute path to the properties file.

```
autoamtion_environment_properties = new Properties();
InputStream iStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(("C:\\automation_environment.properties"));
```

This is giving a `null pointer exception`.

If I have this file in project root folder it works, but I need to access it from outside. Any idea what needs to be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a FileInputStream instead of all that crazy Thread stuff?

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\automation_environment.properties"));
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html

Answer (score 3):

The file has to be in the CLASSPATH for it to work.  Your IDE papers over the difficulty for you, but you'll need to know what you're doing when you don't have the crutch.  Include the directory where the .properties files live in your CLASSPATH.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the full path for the file, you can use FileInputStream class

```
InputStream iStream = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\automation_environment.properties"));
```

Otherwise, please refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/676273/176569

Answer (score 0):

I would try to set \ to / instead like:
`InputStream iStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(("C:/automation_environment.properties"));`