# AWS Lambda function can't read my .bin files (Java)

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I wrote a program in Java and deployed it to AWS Lambda by creating a JAR file containing all the necessary files. My request handler calls a method that tries to create 4 new FileInputStreams, with .bin files as inputs, in a try-catch. For example: InputStream stream = new FileInputStream("random.bin"). However, it's going to the catch statement after trying to create the first one due to an IOException. I have my class files in src/main/java/package. I had the .bin files  in the directory that contains the src folder, and I also tried putting them all in one folder, but that didn't resolve the problem. Very confused how to resolve this problem. It's also not working when I call to read in a text file, so it's not just limited to binaries. I was thinking of putting the binaries in my S3 bucket and somehow reading them from there, but I haven't found anything much online detailing how to do that in Java.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your jar puts files in different locations then what your expect. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984112/jar-cant-access-txt-files) might offer so insight on how to correctly access files in the jar.

Comment: I tried most of the methods outlined in that post, but none of them worked for me.

Comment: what was the issue?

Answer (score -1):

AWS Lambda only allow write access in the `/tmp` folder of your function's filesystem. Try changing your code to match this path and try again.