# java.io.FileNotFoundException getting path to file in java

Tags: java

I have the following code for check if a file exists on some path, if not, that file is copy from the project, and it works.

```
public static void verificarDB() throws IOException {
    File cygnus_db = new File(System.getProperty("user.home")+File.separator+".local"+File.separator+"cygnus"+File.separator+"cygnus_db_local.db");

    if(!cygnus_db.exists()) {

    File source = new File("src/assets/bd/cygnus_db_local.db");
    File target = new File(System.getProperty("user.home")+File.separator+".local"+File.separator+"cygnus"+File.separator+"cygnus_db_local.db");
    FileUtils.copyFile(source, target);
    }
}
```

But when i export my project to a runnable jar i get this exception:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: Source 'src/assets/bd/cygnus_db_local.db' does not exist
>       at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.checkFileRequirements(FileUtils.java:1383)
>       at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1060)
>       at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1028)
>       at pruebas.Main.verificarDB(Main.java:123)
>       at pruebas.Main.main(Main.java:30)

What im doing wrong?

Comment: this is a repeat and the answer is found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20451386/java-jar-cant-find-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jar can't access txt files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984112/jar-cant-access-txt-files)

Comment: And the `src` directory isn't there at runtime.