# Add and use files in JAVA Jar as they would be in the folder

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I have JAVA project which contains some *.sql files and on deploy if there is no database cleated yet I can run some classes which applies those *.sql files on database.
But I have to make JAVA Jar file out of it in order to deploy. I do know how to run any class from jar, but how to add and access my *.sql in the Jar if I do not want extract the files.

The *sql files that I need is being used the following way:

```
mysql -uroot -ppassword < databaseStructure.sql
```

that creates me database. somehow I need access that file out of jar when necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
InputStream stream = YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + pathToYourFile);
```

Example:

You have a file insertSomething.sql in your jar.

```
public static String getResourceContent(
  final String path) throws IOException {
        InputStream stream = YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + path);
        if (stream != null) {
               return IOUtils.toString(stream);
        } 
    }
```

Now you can get the content:

```
String content = getResourceContent("insertSomething.sql");
```

Comment: You can use `IOUtils.toString(InputStream)` to simplify this method.

Comment: Oh thank you, didn't saw the toString-function. I edited my answer.

Comment: You welcome. I think that name of this function is misleading, they could use something like `readToString` instead. It would be easier to run into.

Comment: why do we need the "/" ?

Comment: I had problems in an older version of this function where it wouldn't find the files if I don't put the '/' in front of the filepath. It should work without it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an InputStream from files in your classpath. I'm not sure if that does what you need, exactly.

See this previous SO article on the topic: [Different ways of loading a file as an InputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676250/different-ways-of-loading-a-file-as-an-inputstream)