# images not get loaded after jar creation

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I have made a software in core java and this software will be executed on PC so I have made jar of my software and executed jar on my pc.
jar is executing properly but as i have used images on jbutton so those images are not getting loaded when i execute jar. jbutton and images not shown and creating problem for my whole software...
as when i am loading images on jbutton is like this...

```
public BufferedImage loadImage(String fileName){

BufferedImage buff = null;
try {
    buff = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName));
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
return buff;
```

}

```
     btn.setIcon(new ImageIcon(loadImage("/images/index.jpeg")));
```

Comment: Open the jar using winzip and make sure the file is in place.

Answer (score 0):

The answer (and the links provided in it) to my question [can i use url...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28498668/can-i-use-url-when-executing-java-code-in-eclipse) should be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try to fill out the path name completely to the image file

```
MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath() + "/images/index.jpeg";
```

Replace MyClass with your Class name. This line of code finds the path to the location of your jar file.