# Static method file path

Tags: java, static, absolute-path

How do i get the Path of a file in the same package as the class?

This doesn't work.

```
public static void SaveAllMockData() throws Exception {


        InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("mockdata.json");

    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/676273/4271479

Comment: Thanks for the notice, didn't find that thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
InputStream is = YourClassName.class.getResourceAsStream("mockdata.json"");
```

or you can specify the package path

```
getClass()
    .getResourceAsStream("/abc/efg/mockdata.json");
```

Comment: Perfect, worked like a charm!