# Class Path during unit testing in java

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, classpath

I have a file in /src/main/java which has the following line of code :

```
Test.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.json")
```

and the corresponding resource file is present in /src/main/resources...But we are thinking to remove this test.json from the classpath (src/main/resources) folder and we would include one more jar dependency and that jar would contain this test.json...I have tested with jar dependency and its working fine as it will be in the classPath..But the problem is we have some test cases ..these will fail if we dont include the jar dependency...Is it possible to run the test cases by putting this file in src/test/resources file..Without giving the jar dependencies..

Comment: Did you try? It should take you less than a minute to find out yourself.

Comment: It is not working by placing in src/test/resources..i have tried it..

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Comment: From the pathes I guess that this is a maven project. My guess is that your dependencies are not set-up the way you need it or you put the files in the wrong module.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I am not sure but it should work:

```
URL fileUrl = Test.class.getResource("test.json");
File testFile= new File(FileLocator.toFileURL(fileUrl).getPath());
```

Answer (score 0):

See this one.

[different-ways-of-loading-a-file-as-an-inputstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676250/different-ways-of-loading-a-file-as-an-inputstream)

This one work for me:

Project: newfile

Files:

Test.java

```
package newfile.org;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

myfile.txt

```
It's my file
```

Set as jar library to other project:

MyClass.java

```
    package example;

    import newfile.org.Test;

public class MyClass {

     public static void main(String args[]) {

        try (
                InputStream resourceAsStream = Test.class.getResourceAsStream("myfile.txt")) {
                if(resourceAsStream == null) {
                    System.out.println("it's null");
                }
                int r;
                while((r = resourceAsStream.read()) != -1) {
                    System.out.println((char)r);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Output:

```
I
t
'
s

m
y

f
i
l
e
```