# GetResourceAsStream returning null, file exists

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I know there are many topics out there for this but I have seem to have tried everything.  I can put my file name in there and it finds it if there is a src folder,

```
InputStream is = context.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("file.props");
```

but when we put it on an apache server, a src folder is not automatically created, so it isn't finding it.  I have tried placing it directly in the web-inf folder and

```
InputStream is = context.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF" + File.separator + "file.props");
```

But this is always returned as null.  What is the reason for this?  The file exists there, why can't it find it?

Comment: read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676250/different-ways-of-loading-a-file-as-an-inputstream) , well this has been already explained

Comment: Do not use File.separator. Use the / instead.

Comment: WEB-INF is not on your web app's classpath.  But, WEB-INF/classes is on your web app's classpath. So, put the file file.props  at   WEB-INF/classes/file.prop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be using the wrong `ClassLoader`.  Invoking `context.class.getClassLoader()` provides the `ClassLoader` with which the `ServletContext` class (`context.class`) was loaded.  What you want is the `ClassLoader` for the *web application*'s classes, which would be `context.getClassLoader()`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the ClassLoader if you want to load your file from `/WEB-INF`. Instead, use the `ServletContext`'s method for just that purpose:

```
// In your servlet e.g. doGet method
ServletContext app = super.getServletContext();
InputStream in = app.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/file.props");
```

Note that using `/` is okay regardless of the OS, filesystem, etc.

If you really want to use the `ClassLoader`, take @rickz's advice and move your `file.props` into `WEB-INF/classes`.