# Maven JavaFX Resources ClassLoader InputStream null

Tags: java, maven, classloader, inputstream, javax.imageio

I have the following Problem. I have Images in the Folder with the Path `src/resources`. Now I want to use them in the JavaFX application.

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
InputStream markerInputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("/img/marker.gif");
SurfaceImage surfaceImage = null;
try {
surfaceImage = new SurfaceImage(ImageIO.read(markerInputStream),sector);
} catch (IOException e)
{e.printStackTrace();}
```

This is the StackTrace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1348)
    at map.map.setMarkerPosition(main.java:184)
    at map.map$1.mouseClicked(main.java:151)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6538)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I don't know where the mistake is I have tested the Path `/resources/marker.png` only `/marker.png`

In the pom.xml of this module is the following one.

```
<artifactId>application</artifactId>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.fxml</include>
                    </includes>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
<...>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>gov.nasa</groupId>
                <artifactId>worldwind</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0-986</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.metsci.glimpse</groupId>
                <artifactId>glimpse-extras-worldwind</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.2</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </project>
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Open the JAR to see the contents (ie. `jar tf your.jar | grep gif`). Is your GIF there (or was it PNG, your code use `.gif` your text writes `.png`)? Is it at the path you expected? Could be you need to add `**/*.gif,**/*.png` to the  `include` tag for the Maven assembly plugin?

Answer (score 0):

If classLoader.getResourceAsStream("/img/marker.gif"); is returning null you must ensure that resource is in your classpath.

Build your JAR or WAR and look inside for marker.gif. Maybe it doesn't exist or is under different path.

Comment: You shuld have something like this:

`<build>
   <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/resources</directory>
          <includes>
            <include>*.*</include>           
          </includes>         
      </resource>
</resources>
</build>`

Comment: ok I changed it. In the jar are the pictures but the inputstream is null. I changed the Path in the program to /marker.gif because the pictures are in saved at the first level of the jar

Comment: If you are using getClassLoader() you don't havo to use "/"  before the name of the resource. Read this to understand how the findResource works and how to solve common problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676250/different-ways-of-loading-a-file-as-an-inputstream